# Translation of "an auto-tuned song"

Tags: traduction, anglais, musique

An *auto-tuned song* is a song on where the voice of the singer has been processed to alter the pitch of the voice or the instruments. How would you say "*an auto-tuned song*" in French?

Comment: As-tu quelque chose à proposer ? Qu'as-tu trouvé a partir de l'article de [wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-Tune) ?

Comment: @Laure Son au pitch artificiel, Son au pitch artificiellement corrigé, Son auto-tuné, Son à tonalité artificielle / corrigée. I wonder what French musicians / music fans use, whether there are any standard translation. In the Wikipedia article I couldn't find any use as a verb or adjective.

Comment: Tu devrais inclure dans ta question ce que tu as déjà trouvé dans tes recherches et dire pourquoi ça ne te convient pas et que tu cherches un avis de spécialiste. Ça évitera aussi les réponses du genre « on dit autotune en français » qui est je crois le mot de la presse française en général.

Answer (score 1):

Comme il faut que la voix passe par un micro :

> Enregistrement vocal auto-corrigé.

À partir de *chanter faux*

> Chant réajusté automatiquement.

Pour l'outil on pourrait imaginer un :

> - correcteur de notes chantées,
> - redresseur de fausses notes.

Ou avec un peu d'humour :

> Chasseur de canards d'opéra.